# Longest Palindromic Substring Leetcode Problem, High runtime with Manachers algorithm (O(N))

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, algorithm, palindrome

I am trying to find the longest Palidromic Substring of a given string, LeetCode problem.

I am getting a lesser runtime for expanding centers even though its time complexity is N**2 and manachers is N.

What mistake am I making?

'''
Manachers Algorithm O(N) ---> runtime 2000ms
class Solution(object):

```
def addhashspace(self,s: str) -> str:        
    t = ''
    for i in range(len(s)):
        t += '#' + s[i]
    t = '$' + t + '#@'
    return t

def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
    t = self.addhashspace(s)
    P = [0]*len(t)
    maxi = 0   
    for i in range(len(t)-1):
        C,R = 0,0
        mirr = 2*C - 1
        if(i< R):
            P[i] = min(P[mirr],R - i)
        while(t[i + P[i] + 1] == t[i - P[i] - 1]):
            P[i] += 1
        if(i + P[i] > R):
            C = i
            R = i + P[i]
        if P[i] > maxi:
            maxi = P[i]
            index = i
    ind1 = index//2 - P[index]//2 - maxi%2
    ind2 = index//2 + P[index]//2
    return(s[ind1:ind2])
```

Expnding centers O(N**2) ----> 800ms
class Solution(object):

```
def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
    
    startt = time.time()

    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    start = end = 0
    length = len(s)
    for i in range(length):
        max_len_1 = self.get_max_len(s, i, i + 1)
        max_len_2 = self.get_max_len(s, i, i)
        max_len = max(max_len_1, max_len_2)
        if max_len > end - start:
            start = i - (max_len - 1) // 2
            end = i + max_len // 2
            
    print("Execution Time of 2nd Algo " + str((time.time() - startt) * 10**6) + " ms")
    return s[start: end+1]
        
def get_max_len(self, s: 'list', left: 'int', right: 'int') -> 'int':
    length = len(s)
    i = 1
    max_len = 0
    while left >= 0 and right < length and s[left] == s[right]:
        left -= 1
        right += 1
    return right - left - 1
```

Comment: Guessing expanding centers is O(n) in the average case, and simpler than Manacher's.

Comment: Is this your own implementation? Did you test with varying input sizes? Often, the 'O(x)' complexity analysis will be more indicative on larger inputs, because you are looking at the asymptotic behavior of the algorithm. You also need to consider average and worst case runtimes, which are often different.

Comment: Big-O is worst-case complexity.  Are you sure you made the worst case input for each algorithm?

Comment: Please paste the compilable code so that we could try it out ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

"civilwartestingwhetherthatnaptiono**ranynar**tionsoconceivedandsodedicatedcanlongendureWeareqmetonagreatbattlefiemldoftzhatwarWehavecometodedicpateaportionofthatfieldasafinalrestingplaceforthosewhoheregavetheirlivesthatthatnationmightliveItisaltogetherfangandproperthatweshoulddothisButinalargersensewecannotdedicatewecannotconsecratewecannothallowthisgroundThebravelmenlivinganddeadwhostruggledherehaveconsecrateditfaraboveourpoorponwertoaddordetractTgheworldadswfilllittlenotlenorlongrememberwhatwesayherebutitcanneverforgetwhattheydidhereItisforusthelivingrathertobededicatedheretotheulnfinishedworkwhichtheywhofoughtherehavethusfarsonoblyadvancedItisratherforustobeherededicatedtothegreattdafskremainingbeforeusthatfromthesehonoreddeadwetakeincreaseddevotiontothatcauseforwhichtheygavethelastpfullmeasureofdevotionthatweherehighlyresolvethatthesedeadshallnothavediedinvainthatthisnationunsderGodshallhaveanewbirthoffreedomandthatgovernmentofthepeoplebythepeopleforthepeopleshallnotperishfromtheearth"

- This is the worst case test input among other inputs I was using to compare the two algorithms. I used a counter to see the number of iterations it took to find the palindrome "ranynar" in the given string.
- Not shockingly - Manachers took **1189** iterations where as Expanding Centers took **1094** iterations.
- Definitely Manachers takes more computational time in each iteration so that explains the runtime difference.

I guess my test input size has been small to really take advantage of O(N) time complexity as Manachers does require more steps in each iteration.

I will have to test with a dataset with larger input sizes to see the difference in the two.